# Combining different enums into one parameter C#

Tags: c#, events, enums, action

I am starting a class for Events.
Currently there are two enums.

```
[Flag]
public enum Status
{
    statusA,
    statusB,
    statusC,
    statusD,
}

[Flag]
public enum StatusType{
    Request,
    Success,
    Fail,
    Start,
    End
}
```

I would like to be able to raise the event, Action RequestingStatusA (Status.StatusA & StatusType.Request) for example.
This of course, gives errors. Is there anyway to combine them on the fly but make it as a signature such that the event handler would recognise it.

Should I be even doing it this way even?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Not only that, but you will have collisions if you try to map the non-transformed bit values - so don't blinding consider casting to `int` :)

Why not create (and pass) a new type that wraps values of *both* enum types?

```
struct RequestStatus {
  // implement as desired
  public StatusType Type { get; set; }
  public Status Status { get; set; }
}

Action RequestingStatusA (RequestStatus status) {
  ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My intention was to make it easier to implement events using this class. What would the difference then be from Action <Status,StatusType> RequestingStatusA (Status.StatusA, StatusType.Request), skipping the structure altogether. This would be acceptable, but would be "encumbering". Perhaps i've got the entire design wrong in the first place?

Comment: @Tyhja It's not necessarily better - you'll have to decide that - but using an aggregate type "keeps" the values as one unit. (Also, in some cases I have found that it can make the application easier to extend for things I didn't consider before: perhaps there is also a Message to be associated with the result?)

Comment: I see. Thanks. I think that will be outside the scope of the original question. I'll take a look and I'll post another if I have problems.